# Using different versions of spring security with spring session stored in redis

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-session

I need to share session between two spring applications. One of them is very big old app written in spring 3.2 and with spring security 3.1.6. The second one is based on spring boot 1.3.3. Session should be shared via redis server. Users can communicate directly only with the old application. The new one will be accessible only by the old application.

The goal is to have access to username and be able to verify user rights in the new app based on the information stored in redis by the old application.

I tried to achieve this via spring-session. I managed to store session data in redis in the old application using very simple configuration. In pom.xml I added dependency to spring-session-data-redis

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

In spring configuration I added two beans:

- org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration
- org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory

And in web.xml one more filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But after configuring the new application to use spring session by adding two annotations to config class:

- @EnableWebSecurity
- @EnableRedisHttpSession

And adding HeaderHttpSessionStrategy bean, when I try to reach the new application with active session id in x-auth-token header I get exception:

```
 java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 310, local class serialVersionUID = 400
```

I do not need all information from the old apps session, only the username and user roles to verify some access credentials. I tried to google about custom session serialization and try to serialize only part of the session and in such way that it will be independent from spring-security version. Unfortunately I failed in this idea. I also try to configure the old spring-security version in the new app, but it also failed...

Is there any simple way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You can provide a custom serialization strategy. We are working on providing Spring Security / Jackson support. You can find a PR https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/3812 for the work

I should note that going forward Spring Security (i.e. Spring Security 4.1+) is keeping a constant serialization id to prevent issues.

Comment: I also thought about writing some custom serializer/deserializer to json and attach it to spring session, but at the first glance it looks pretty complicated and not well documented. I didn't have time yet to figure out how to do it, but the case is still open. Thanks for PR link.

Comment: See my answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64018670/4863347.   Best info on serializing SecurityContext as JSON is article here: https://rusyasoft.github.io/spring-security/2019/01/14/spring-security-session-redis-json/