# How to catch redis.serializer.SerializationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, redis

I have application on Spring framework(4.1.6), using Spring Security 4.0.1. I'm use @EnableRedisHttpSession and @EnableSpringHttpSession in application, and all work fine. But after upgrade version of Spring Security to 4.2.1 i have a problem with Serialization old version on new package.

My stacktrace is:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception
 org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 400, local class serialVersionUID = 420
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:316)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashMap(AbstractOperations.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:227)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:101)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:421)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:392)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:252)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:270)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:286)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 400, local class serialVersionUID = 420
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:39)
    ... 53 more
```

I don't understand, how to catch this exception inside Spring.

My question is:" How to catch this exception, to further display a simple error page?".

P.S. I can't clean old sessions. Any help will be cool!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle exceptions with Spring AOP, @Aspect

```
    public class ErrorInterceptor{
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* your.package..* (..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void errorInterceptorForSerializationException(SerializationException ex) {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE WITH EX
        logger.error( ex.getCause().getMessage());
    }
 @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* your.package..* (..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void errorInterceptorForSerializationFailedException(SerializationFailedException ex) {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE WITH EX
        logger.error( ex.getCause().getMessage());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not supported by Spring Session as of Spring Boot 2.3.3, Spring 5.x.

That said, as long as all apps have a fairly current version of Spring Security, the project has stopped updating the value of serialVersionUID to minimize version conflicts.

Otherwise, there are a couple work-arounds that can either ease transistions or, if you're willing to do some work, serialize SecurityContext class as JSON.

But the available information is scattered and sometimes conflicting.  Tread carefully.

Bullet Points:

- [SerializationFailedException after re-deploying with changed session object](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/280)
- [Handling Deserialization Errors in Spring Redis Sessions](https://sadique.io/blog/2016/11/02/handling-deserialization-errors-in-spring-redis-sessions/)
- [Storing JSON Formatted Spring Session in Redis](https://rusyasoft.github.io/spring-security/2019/01/14/spring-security-session-redis-json/)

More details:

1. There are a bunch of issues logged on Spring Session related to this issue.  None has actually solved the problem fully.
2. The simplest work-around deletes the "old" sessions which most likely forces the user to log in again (but, if remember me tokens are used, may not be visible to the user).
3. With some deeper Spring Boot configuration hacking, it appears it *may* be possible to store your Spring Security session in JSON format.  This *may* allow different apps running different versions of Spring Security to share sessions.   YMMV.